# C++/CLI Threading - InvalidProgramException

Tags: multithreading, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am using C++/CLI to write a kind of downloader. It is supposed to show the status of the download in a progress bar. In order for the download not to block the form, I need to run it in a background thread, but in order to access the progress bar, I need a pointer to it in my download function. Therefore, I need to start the thread with the form (or progress bar, doesn't matter) as an argument. For this, I wrote a little threading wrapper class:

```
typedef System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Object^> ArgList;

ref class GCThread {

private:
    void (*entryPoint)(System::Object^);
    ArgList^ arguments;
public:
    GCThread(void (*entryPoint)(System::Object^)) { this->entryPoint = entryPoint; arguments = gcnew ArgList(); };
    void addArgument(System::Object^ obj) { arguments->Add(obj); };
    void start();
};

void GCThread::start() {

    System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart^ ts = gcnew System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart(&entryPoint);
    System::Threading::Thread^ t = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(ts);
    t->Start((System::Object^) arguments);
}
```

When trying to call the function like this

```
GCThread^ thread = gcnew GCThread(downloadFiles);
thread->addArgument(btnLogin);
thread->addArgument(pgrDownload);
thread->start();
```

with downloadFiles being a global method defined as

```
void __clrcall downloadFiles(System::Object^);
```

I get a System::InvalidProgramException: The Common Language Runtime has found an invalid program when creating the parameterized thread start object. What am I doing wrong? Why can't you create global variables for gc types? I know it's completely against the purpose of a garbage collector to have global variables, but at least having the opportunity to decide for yourself would be nice.

By the way, I'm using VC++ 2008.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  ... ts = gcnew System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart(&entryPoint)
```

You fooled the compiler into accepting an invalid program.  That method requires a *delegate object*, you passed an unmanaged function pointer.  This is a flaw in the compiler, it should have generated a diagnostic.  Notable is that the IntelliSense parser *does* complain.  It gets more spectacular when you remove the & operator, that invokes a compiler crash.  Probably ought to use the proper name for this: a compiler bug.

You'll need to get ahead by declaring a proper delegate type with the *delegate* keyword.  A rewrite of your code that (I think) does what you want to do:

```
using namespace System;

typedef System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Object^> ArgList;

ref class GCThread {
public:
    delegate void EntryPoint(ArgList^ args);
private:
    EntryPoint^ entryPoint;
    ArgList^ arguments;
    void startFunc(Object^ args);
public:
    GCThread(EntryPoint^ start) { this->entryPoint = start; arguments = gcnew ArgList(); };
    void addArgument(System::Object^ obj) { arguments->Add(obj); };
    void start();
};

void GCThread::startFunc(Object^ args) {
    this->entryPoint(safe_cast<ArgList^>(args));    
}

void GCThread::start() {
    auto t = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &GCThread::startFunc));
    t->Start(arguments);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
void ExampleThread(ArgList^ args) {
    // etc..
}
....
auto t = gcnew GCThread(gcnew GCThread::EntryPoint(&ExampleThread));
t->addArgument(42);
t->start();
```

---

The much less painful way to go about it is to declare only a simple class type that just stores the arguments and use a vanilla Thread.  Using safe_cast<> in the thread function to recover the arguments.  Not even necessary in your case since you want to use List<>.  In other words:

```
void ExampleThread(Object^ arg) {
    auto args = safe_cast<List<Object^>^>(arg);
    // etc...
}
...

auto arg = gcnew List<Object^>;
arg->Add(42);
auto t2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(&ExampleThread2));
t2->Start(arg);
```

Comment: Perfect, that did exactly what it should. Thanks!